# Promise.all not waiting for all response Azure Node.js Function

Tags: node.js, https, async-await, azure-functions, es6-promise

Hi I have wrote an code which will call n times an external api and then its response will pass to one more function and finally the consolidated response will be returned by the Azure function, but it seems I am not getting response for all items. It keeps on changing every time I run this code, I think there is a issue with my promise.all approach. Please look into my code

```
const axios = require('axios');
let globalContext;
var  globalRes = { status: true, products: [] }
const extractProuctFromLUISRes = async (jsonRes, Query) => {
    var quantArray = [];
    var resp = { quantity: 1, UOM: "", query: Query }
    if (jsonRes.entities.hasOwnProperty("UOM") === true) {
        if (jsonRes.entities.UOM.length > 0) {
            resp.UOM = jsonRes.entities.UOM[0][0]
        }
    }
    globalRes.products.push(resp);
}

const splitAndGetProduct = async (text) => {
    //split based on \n
    splitedEmail = text.split("\n");
    let luisCallPromises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < splitedEmail.length; i++) {
        if (splitedEmail[i].length > 5) {
            luisCallPromises.push(callLuisProducts(splitedEmail[i]));
        }
    }

    let luisResponses = await Promise.all(luisCallPromises);
    for (let luisResponseIterator=0; luisResponseIterator<luisResponses.length; ++luisResponseIterator) {
        if(luisResponses[luisResponseIterator])
            await extractProuctFromLUISRes(luisResponses[luisResponseIterator].prediction, luisResponses[luisResponseIterator].query);
    }
}

const callLuisProducts = async (utterance) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        var finalApiCall = "#httpsCallquery=" + encodeURIComponent(utterance.substring(0, 500));
        //axios call
        try {
            let a = await axios.get(finalApiCall);
            if (a.status == 200) {
                var jsonBody = a.data;
                if (jsonBody.prediction.topIntent == "product") {
                    resolve(jsonBody);
                } else {
                    resolve(false);
                }
            } else {
                resolve(false);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            resolve(false);
        }
    });
}

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    globalContext = context;
    var inputArray = JSON.parse(req.body.attachmentProcessed);
    await splitAndGetProduct(inputArray);
    finalResolve();
}

function finalResolve() {
    globalContext.res = {
        body: globalRes
    };
    globalRes = { status: true, products: [] }
    globalContext.done();
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the result of `console.log(luisCallPromises)` before `Promise.all`?

Comment: 2020-02-14T13:10:51.443 [Information] [
  Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> }
]

Answer (score 0):

the azure function do not work with arrow functions. you need to rewrite your code using

```
try{ 
    let answer=await 
    }
catch(e){}
```

structure